# How does acacia affect the growth of nearby plants?

Tags: botany, allelopathy

I know acacia will make the soil more acidic, but how? I tried to search online, but cannot really find something useful.

Comment: What is the source of the claim that acacia makes the soil more acidic?

Comment: @LinuxBlanket My teacher told me that it will

Comment: The only hint to acacia making soil more acidic I could find at all was this: http://crcleme.org.au/Pubs/Advancesinregolith/Leonard_Field.pdf There it is somewhat stated that because they fix nitrogen, the soil acidity increases around the root. I don't know what to make of this at all, I was just curious and found it unexpectedly hard to find information on.

Comment: You say "affect the growth of nearby plants". Is this interaction positive or negative for the other plants?

Comment: try reading articles similar to [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037811279503581T) and [here](https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ja.2014.158.168) and update your post with what you've learned. We expect question askers to do their own research before posting questions. See the help page for asking good questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> [Allelopathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allelopathy) is a biological phenomenon by which an organism produces one or more biochemicals that influence the germination, growth, survival, and reproduction of other organisms. These biochemicals are known as allelochemicals and can have beneficial (positive allelopathy) or detrimental (negative allelopathy) effects on the target organisms and the community.

Now to the *Acacia* case.

First of all, *Acacia* is a genus comprehending almost [400 species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Acacia_species), so my answer will cover all allelopathy cases involving one species belinging to this genus.

[This article](https://www.scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ja.2014.158.168&org=11) states that *Acacia mangium* leaf extracts and forest soil negatively affects germination and growth of paddy, and [this other one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037811279503581T) reports phytotoxic effects of *Acacia melanoxylon* on *Lectuca sativa* (lettuce) germination and growth.

As to **how** *Acacia* species can have an allelopathic effect on nearby plants, [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926669016300206) evaluated the content the phytochemical composition of *Acacia cyclops, Acacia mollissima* and *Acacia cyanophylla* pods and seeds and the phytotoxic effect on lettuce seed sprouting. It states that:

- All extracts of the three species of *Acacia* contain saponins and condensed tannins.
- The most toxic one was the ethyl acetate extract of seeds from *A. cyanophylla*, a total inhibition of growth (100%) was registered.
- A new triterpenoid saponin called mollisside B has been registered for the first time in the *Acacia* genus and may be responsible of part of the allelopathic effect on lettuce.